# Using apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost

i am trying to set up my apache with 2 virtual hosts:

```
Listen 11.22.33.44:8080

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName servername.com/stable
    DocumentRoot /home/deploy/producao/servername.com/current/public
    <Directory /home/deploy/producao/servername.com/current/public>
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName servername.com/stable
    DocumentRoot /home/deploy/teste/servername.com/current/public
    <Directory /home/deploy/teste/servername.com/current/public>
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But all is wrong.
What i want is, when i type servername.com/stable i get one document root and when i use servername.com/testing i get onother one.

I tryed several things but none work, like

```
<VirtualHost servername.com/stable>
<VirtualHost servername.com/testing>
```

and using

```
ServerName servername.com
ServerPath /stable
...
ServerName servername.com
ServerPath /testing
```

But none of this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ServerName` directives are incorrect. You can only specify a DNS hostname with that directive, **NOT** a server path.
e.g.

```
ServerName example.com
ServerName example.net
```

would be correct. You're just trying to host two different sites in subdirectories of the SAME server name. For that, you don't need two virtualhost directives. Just a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` within a single vhost, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com
    <Location /site1>
        ... site1 settings here
    </Location>
    <Location /site2>
        ... site2 settings here
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```